# C Project scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

Here is my code, my statements is that when while loop starts to run show options and scan the selection at first iteration but in second iteration choice is not assigned again and previous selection is remembered. What is the problem ? (I am using VS2012)

```
while (!done){
    int choice;

    printf("\n------- STUDENT INFORMATION SYSTEM MAIN MENU --------\n");
    printf("1-Load students from the database\n");
    printf("2-Print existing students on the screen\n");
    printf("3-Add a new student\n");
    printf("4-Delete an existing student\n");
    printf("5-Find an existing student\n");
    printf("6-Quit\n");
    printf("====> Choice? ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice){
      case 1:
        LoadStudentsFromDatabase();
        printf("Students loaded from database successfully\n");
        break;

      case 2:
        PrintExistingStudentsOnTheScreen();
        break;

      case 3:
        printf("\nFirstName: "); scanf("%s", s.firstName);

    printf("LastName: "); scanf("%s", s.lastName);
        printf("ID: "); scanf("%d", &s.id);
        printf("Gpa: "); scanf("%f", &s.gpa);
        printf("Department: "); scanf("%d", &s.department);

        AddStudent(&s);
        printf("1 student added\n");
        break;

      case 4:
        printf("\nID? "); scanf("%d", &id);
        if (DeleteStudent(id)){
          printf("Student deleted successfully\n");
        } else {
          printf("Failed to delete the student. Does not exist?\n");
        } /* end-else */
        break;

      case 5:
        printf("\nID? "); scanf("%d", &id);
        ps = FindStudent(id);
        if (ps == NULL){
          printf("Student not found\n");
        } else {
          char *depts[] = {"CS", "EE", "IE", "CE", "ME"};
          printf("+--------------------+--------------------+------+------+------+\n");
          printf("|    FirstName       |     LastName       |  ID  |  GPA | Dept |\n");
          printf("+--------------------+--------------------+------+------+------+\n");
          printf("|%20s|%20s|%6d|%6.2f|%6s|\n", ps->firstName, ps->lastName, ps->id, ps->gpa, depts[ps->department]);
          printf("+--------------------+--------------------+------+------+------+\n");
        } //end-else
        break;

      case 6:
        done = 1;
        break;

      default:
        printf("!!!!!!!!!! Invalid choice. Try again :-))\n");
        break;
    } /* end-switch */
  } /* end-while */
```

Comment: You really should verify the return value of the scanf call (and, in fact, of most functions declared in `<stdio.h>`), as eg `if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1) /* error */;`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. Can you come up with an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: [Your code at ideone (SSCCE'd by me)](http://ideone.com/mwzH4f) behaves as expected!

Comment: Show what `AddStudent` does and where/how `s` is declared

Comment: *"What is the problem ?"* A failure to use a **debugger** is the most immediate problem. You'd be amazed how quickly the other "problems" are solved once that one is addressed. And considering you're using Visual Studio, which has arguably the finest integrated debugger on the market, there is little-reason not to address is.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that when you call scanf for the second time around there is an error. Probably because a non digit input is waiting to be read on stdin. Maybe you didn't fully read all your input during the body of your code last time around? scanf tries to read a digit and only a digit because of your conversion format `%d` so if the next thing to be read is not a digit it fails it returns an error and leaves `choice` untouched. You do not check for this error so assume choice contains a newly entered value when in fact it just contains whatever it contained before scanf was called. scanf can also fail for more error like reasons as well but I suspect thats not the case here.

My suggestion would be:

a) check the return value of scanf. It should return 1 in your case. If it does not there has been an error. You can either bail out or just present the menu again.

b) Have a look at fpurge/fflush. I'm not sure what will be available to you using VC++ but Google will find you equivalents. Those functions can be used to discard pending input before calling scanf.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is behaving as expected.

The behaviour can be reproduced with the following input

```
FirstName: f
LastName: l
ID: 1
Gpa: 2
Department: d
```

`Department` expects an `int` as input, when you type in something else,  `d` in this case, the [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) keeps looking for an `int` as you are looping, so the line `scanf("%d", &choice);` fails too to read an `int` and `choice` is not reassigned a new value, so the `switch` statement always sees the last valid value for `choice`. the loop pauses then at the next read attempt.

To solve your problem you need to validate the input and go to the next step only if the input you are expecting is valid. You can do this by checking the return value of [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) witch is the number of items successfully parsed according to the conversion patterns, in your case you want to read only `one` item.

Here is a basic way how you could validate an integer input

```
int read_integer(char* what)
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("%s: ", what);
    int r = scanf("%d", &i);
    while(r == 0) {
        while('\n' != getchar())
            // consume the rest of input until a LF comes (enter pressed)
            ;
        printf("Bad input for %s, try again (r=%d)\n", what, r);
        printf("%s: ", what);
        r = scanf("%d", &i);
    }
    return i;
}
```

and here how you could read `Department`

```
int department = read_integer("Department");
```

You could also write a similar function for `float` -> `float read_float(char*){...}`