# Using while (scanf(...)==0) properly

Tags: return, scanf

I have a question regarding the use of scanf with the invalid return. Here is a fragment of code I am testing:

```
printf("Please enter a number\n");
while (scanf("%d",&number)==0)
{
    printf("Try again.\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);
}
```

My reasoning suggests that if an invalid type is used, my second scanf should ask again and test the new entered value. However, this is not the case and the Try again message never stops printing so I have to terminate it manually. I am not sure why this is happening.  I don't want to have to use the scanf before the while loop if possible although I know this is a possible workaround. I would appreciate any help on this matter. Thanks.

Comment: The most obvious problem: Your loop calls `scanf` *twice* for each time it tests the result. That can't possibly be right.

Comment: Yo are not catching the return of in-loop scanf! and the input stream is still unconsumed therefor you get an endless loop. i've [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447810/c-project-scanf/15448405#15448405) a simlar question earlier today have alook at it

Comment: EDIT: Thank you very much for saving the rest of my program! I truly appreciate your help :).

Answer (score 4):

`scanf` does not return an error code. It returns the number of conversions successfully performed.

As for the endless loop, it doesn't consume the input that can't be converted. So it's repeatedly trying to match the same string as a number. Try using `fgets` to discard the offending input.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, we haven't been introduced to fgets in my programming class and so we aren't allowed to use it. What I want to achieve is the following: Ask the user for input. If this input is of the same type as int, then scanf would return 1 and we could move on with the rest of the code. However, if scanf returns 0, I have to re-ask until I get an int type.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` may return an `EOF` to indicate an input failure.

"The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure." C11 7.21.6.4

The use of `scanf("%d", ...` after a failed `scanf("%d", ...` only result in an infinite loop as each `scanf()` is trying to consume a non-digit, no-space and failing.  To get past the problem, the offending data must be consumed.

```
printf("Please enter a number\n");
int number;
int Count;
while ((Count = scanf("%d",&number)) != 1) {
  if (Count < 0) {
    exit(1); // No more input possible
  }
  // Some char is preventing scanf() from reading an int
  scanf("%*c");  // Get it and throw away
  printf("Try again.\n");
}
printf("number = %d\n", number);
```